# How can I create photo effects in Android?

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing, photo

I'd like to make an Android app that lets a user apply cool effects to photos taken with the camera. There are already a few out there, I know, but I'd like to try my own hand at one.

I have been googling and stack-overflowing, but so far I've mostly found some references to published papers or books. I am ordering this one from Amazon presently - [Digital Image Processing: An Algorithmic Introduction using Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846283795)

After some reading, I think I have a basic understanding of manipulating the RGB values for all the pixels in the image. My main question is how do I come up with a transformation that produces cool effects?

By cool effects I mean some like those in these iPhone apps:

- [ToyCamera](http://artandmobile.com/toycamera)
- [Polarize](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/polarize/id301027161?mt=8#)

I already have quite a bit of experience with Java, and I've made my first app for android already. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your exact question? How those effects can be achieved in general ('language-agnostic'), or how to do them in java and what libraries are best suited for such a task?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to know both. I haven't seen any concrete examples of code that actually created a polaroid effect (for example) from a .jpg. I assume it is a matter of applying the right contrast transformation to an image and maybe also a mask to darken the edges (to simulate the uneven exposure).

Since I'm thinking of implementing this for android, I'd also be happy to see some hints on what platform specific classes could be used.

Answer (score 1):

There are specific classes to do this for you!

[Take a look here for grayscale image processing](http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/03/convert-color-image-to-gray-scale-image.html)

[Here is something in C# which is similar enough to java that you should get the idea.](http://www.sergemeunier.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-getting-that-old-time-effect-with-sepia/)

If you want to do something unique you might have to experiment with the tweaking of the RGB ratios yourself.